# Python cgi script inserts only integers into mysql database

Tags: python, python-3.x, cgi, mysql-python, cgi-bin

I started scripting in Python and I ran a into weird problem.

I am trying to insert some values into mysql database.
Database fields are varchar, utf-8 unicode

Using Python 3.2 and wamp server 2.2(apache 2.2.21, mysql 5.5.20)

If I try print(ime), print(prezime) etc. it prints values of a form from another page, so I am getting correct values.

if I write sql statement as:

```
"INSERT INTO Clanovi(CL_Ime,CL_Prezime, CL_Email, CL_Tel) VALUES ("aa","aa","aa","aa")"
```

it inserts those values into database

if I write:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Clanovi(CL_Ime,CL_Prezime, CL_Email, CL_Tel) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)",(ime,prezime,email,tel)
```

it doesnt work

finaly if I put

sql = "INSERT INTO Clanovi(CL_Ime,CL_Prezime, CL_Email, CL_Tel) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)"%(ime,prezime,email,tel)

if I put only numbers into form fields it will commit to database (add new data)
ime= 21 prezime= 232 email =123 tel=123
if I put anything else like letters it wont add new row to database
ime= smth prezime=blabla email = aa tel =dada

(I know this method has security risk)

here is whole code ( I putted print(sql) just to see what my query looks like at the end)

```
#!c:\python32\python.exe
import MySQLdb
import cgi
print ("Content-type: text/html\n\n")

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
ime =form["ime"].value
prezime = form["prezime"].value
email= form["email"].value
tel = form["tel"].value 
print(ime)      
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","biblioteka" )

cursor = db.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO Clanovi(CL_Ime,CL_Prezime, CL_Email, CL_Tel) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)"%(ime,prezime,email,tel)
print(sql)
try:
   cursor.execute(sql)
   db.commit()
except:
   db.rollback()
db.close()
```

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection and also see the 'parameters' argument of cursor.execute()

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn’t assemble your query using Python’s string operations because doing so is insecure; it makes your program vulnerable to an SQL injection attack.
Instead, use the DB-API’s parameter substitution. Put `?` as a placeholder wherever you want to use a value, and then provide a tuple of values as the second argument to the cursor’s `execute()` method:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO Clanovi(CL_Ime,CL_Prezime, CL_Email, CL_Tel) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"
print(sql)
try:
   cursor.execute(sql, (ime, prezime, email, tel))
   db.commit()
except:
   db.rollback()
db.close()
```

**Update**: Luke is right (see comments): MySQL uses '%s' instead of '?

Updated sql-statement: `sql = "INSERT INTO Clanovi(CL_Ime,CL_Prezime, CL_Email, CL_Tel) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"`

Comment: MySQLdb uses `%s` as its placeholder, not `?`.  Your code above will give a 'not all arguments converted during string formatting' error.